# Outlook macro to collect/extract data from "Subject field" of numerous messages into a text file

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

Our firewall users send messages requesting unblocking certain websites that they believe shouldn't be blocked. Their messages subject fields contain such websites urls. In fact, one url is sent per message. Due to the increase in number of users, hundreds or may be thousands of messages are expected to be received per day.

Is there an Outlook macro that will collect or extract such urls (from received messages subject fields) into one single text file without having to open any message?

Deeply appreciating any assistance with this matter.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what should trigger this 'retrieving' action? which additional parameter should decide that you want 'this email subject' but 'not the other one'- any key word in the subject, any folder where you send these e-mails, any recipient's address?

Comment: Sure.. first, retrieving action will be triggered manually and daily upon other workload. Second, "http://" and "classified under:" are both key "words" in the subject field that are used as parameters to select their message and not another one. Third, retrieving action is run on received messages in the inbox of firewall_support@iuass.org account which is viewed and managed on MS Outlook. Retrieving action is expected to yield a simple text file where data in subject fields are collected before it (retrieving action) deletes processed messages. Hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please write this code to your Outlook VBA module. Change some names of folders and destination file in some lines below. For other information see comments inside sub.

```
Sub Retrieve_http()

'our Outlook folder- deifinitions
    Dim myItem As MailItem
    Dim myFolder As Folder
    Dim myNamespace As NameSpace
    Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    'put your folders name here
    '1st one is store folder which should refer to firewall_support@iuass.org
    'second is possibly 'inbox folder'
    Set myFolder = myNamespace.folders("firewall_support@iuass.org").folders("inbox")

'destination file
    Dim resFile As String
        resFile = "c:\Users\Kazik\Desktop\httpRequest.txt"
    Dim ff As Byte
        ff = FreeFile()
    'creating or opening it- each time you run this macro we will append data
    'until deletion of either file or its content
    Open resFile For Append As #ff

    For Each myItem In myFolder.items
        If InStr(1, myItem.Subject, "http://") > 0 And _
            InStr(1, myItem.Subject, "classified under:") > 0 Then
                'write to file
                Write #ff, myItem.Subject

        End If
    Next
    Close #ff
End Sub
```

**EDIT** to include appropriate deletion process and reference of the code to the picture.

The following picture present Outlook window (Polish version) where: Business Mail is one of Top Folders (which refers to separate .pst file). 'Skrzynka odbiorcza' is just 'inbox'.

[image]

Code which searches for certain emails, retrieves subject of emails and deletes emails afterwards looks as follow:

```
Sub Retrieve_http()

'our Outlook folder- deifinitions
    Dim myItem As MailItem
    Dim myFolder As Folder
    Dim myNamespace As NameSpace
    Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    'put your folders name here
    Set myFolder = myNamespace.folders("Business Mail").folders("skrzynka odbiorcza")

'destination file
    Dim resFile As String
        resFile = "c:\Users\Kazik\Desktop\httpRequest.txt"
    Dim ff As Byte
        ff = FreeFile()
    'creating or opening it- each time you run this macro we will append data
    'until deletion of either file or its content
    Open resFile For Append As #ff
    Dim i!
    For i = myFolder.items.Count To 1 Step -1
        If InStr(1, myFolder.items(i).Subject, "http://") > 0 And _
            InStr(1, myFolder.items(i).Subject, "classified under") > 0 Then
                'write to file
                Write #ff, myFolder.items(i).Subject
                'delete item
                myFolder.items(i).Delete
        End If
    Next
    Close #ff
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much Kazik for your professional promptness, producing such a masterpiece. I still, though, wonder if this code line: Set myFolder = myNamespace.Folders("firewall_support@iuass.org").Folders("inbox") means the .pst file in first "Folders"? and if it is yes, I did put my path to it as: "C:\Users\Josef Miller\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\(IUASS) Firewall Support.pst" and it stopped for debugging highlighting previous code line. Any suggestions?

Comment: I would say 'yes, in some way'. `.Folders("firewall_support@iuass.org").` is connected with `.pst` file but you can't set reference in the way you did. In few words:`.pst`is a file and you could deal with it as a file (different logic needed which I even don't know). `myFolder` is object, which means it converts `.pst` into Outlook objects structure. If you have any problems with setting references to `myFolder` just experiment with names (or indexes instead). I did check the code before posting :)

Comment: Thank you Kazik for your answer which actually made me spend an entire day in a "trial and error" process which eventually ended in no success. I can't make this code work for me as I failed to assign, or point to, the `.pst` folder. Any suggestions from you are highly valued to me. Thanking you.

Comment: Me again, but this time with success!! The solution was extremely simple, but I was actually thinking and searching in a different direction. I changed the `.pst` file name into `firewall_support` without any suffixes or prefixes which I mentioned earlier in my reply to your answer, and it **DID WORK!!** Thank you very very much Kazik for your effort and time you spent to save my effort and time. All the best.

Comment: Running and testing it, I found it just takes 4 messages at a time, despite there are over 280 messages; any reason for that to happen?

Comment: I think I made a logic mistake with deletion :) If we delete we should iterate from last to first element. So, for test try to remove `.delete` line, for total improvement try to change the loop into this one: `For i=myFolder.Items.Count to 1 step -1`. I hope it solves the problem...

Comment: I'm really sorry, I think I'm messing it up with my trial and error. Could you please post your modification in the code itself, that will make it much more understandable to me. My apologies for any inconvenience caused by this request.

Comment: With all respect and gratitude I thank you for your marvelous script that does really turn my work into fun. All the best Kazik.

Comment: Is it possible to modify this to search the email body for IP addresses and write to file?    

    `If InStr(1, myFolder.items(i).Subject, "http://") > 0 And _
            InStr(1, myFolder.items(i).Subject, "classified under") > 0 Then`

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution to your problem :)

When you make a For Each Outlook it enumerating each email.
If you move any email within the loop For Each, then Outlook changes the number of all the emails of the folder but doesn't change the iteration number of your loop. This results in several messages that will not be read.

Solution is to make a loop starting from the last email as mentioned here
[Outlook macro to collect/extract data from "Subject field" of numerous messages into a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16225353/outlook-macro-to-collect-extract-data-from-subject-field-of-numerous-messages)

CODE: 
Replace (For Each InboxMsg In Inbox.Items) with

For i = Inbox.Items.Count To 1 Step -1 'Iterates from the end backwards
    Set InboxMsg = Inbox.Items(i)